# Any Apps script command to add URL into google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am converting google sheets rows into individual docs & it is working fine , except for adding the URL.
For adding the text, I am using:
**body.replaceText("{Curr3}",Curr3);**

For adding a link I am using
**body.appendParagraph("Id3").setLinkUrl(Id3);**

but it is not putting it the way I want (i have put the other data in a table, & with the (appendparagraph) it is going outside the table.

How can I put it next to the text  ?

I am adding you the google sheet example from here- when you can see all the script attached to it & when you click on TO DOC function, the script runs & generate the related documents:
The google sheet from here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C1Vh4PYOm2jbt2t8x3V-aPXjSFQr8j6bbNrY26e4f6Y/edit?usp=sharing

the script included is here:

```
  //MAIN FUNCTION
function createBulkPDFs() {
//new updated links 2024 - docfile -temp Folder(Application File)
const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("13P3lyKvx_RzxFn4wpshwMO58FKSSlobJjzRzvs9bEUY");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById ("1jQT82KcHcBZX-JbaMI3Po-LiOCGdwjfJ");
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById ("1sZvoabFvac6RicOAeZ6JnPtQJt_oNyvA");
const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("info")
//read 4 well - i have changed getlastrow-1 instead of -2
const data = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();

data.forEach(row=> {
// 8
createPDF(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],
row[0],docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder);
});
}

function createPDF (Col1,Col2,Id1,Id2,
pdfName, docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder) {

//not moved the tempFile
const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder).setName(pdfName);

 
 const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
 //important
 const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
 //REPLACE  variables in text with those here
 body.replaceText("{Col1}",Col1);
 body.replaceText("{Col2}",Col2);
   
body.appendParagraph("Id1").setLinkUrl(Id1);
body.appendParagraph("Id2").setLinkUrl(Id2);
 tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
}
```

& here is the resulting docs generated in this folder:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jQT82KcHcBZX-JbaMI3Po-LiOCGdwjfJ?usp=drive_link

And the google doc template is from here:
[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13P3lyKvx_RzxFn4wpshwMO58FKSSlobJjzRzvs9bEUY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue and your expected result from your showing script and `but it is not putting it the way I want (i have put the other data in a table, & with the (appendparagraph) it is going outside the table. How can I put it next to the text ?`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I am sorry - I have added now all the scripts , sheet & resulting document.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing discussions and the answer.

Comment: Would you please share your doc file template.

Comment: Sure, here you go:
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13P3lyKvx_RzxFn4wpshwMO58FKSSlobJjzRzvs9bEUY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `Sure, here you go` - That isn't the template mentioned in the question. `it is not putting it the way I want (i have put the other data in a table, & with the (appendparagraph) it is going outside the table.` Your objective is to put the URLs (the **loooong** 85 character URLs) _in_ the table. The script refers to two urls (`Id1` & `Id2`) and their placeholders. Your template document doesn't mention "Id1" or "Id2" or which placeholder/cell (if any) are intended to hold the URLs. Would you please ensure that your sample data aligns with your template and that they both align with your script.